# How to fix “Error : can't share your screen” with Google Meet in Google Chrome Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-hangouts

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with operating system loaded Windows 8.1 Pro and using Google Chrome version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am able to use Hangouts / Google Meet / Google Chat for chat, video & audio call, as well as joining meetings. For some reason, I'm unable to share my screen using Google Meet.

I have tried with other Mozilla FireFox and I am able to share my screen but not with Google Chrome. While sharing screen it throws the following error:

> Can't share your screen. Sorry, an error has occurred when screen sharing

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am attaching screen shots as well for better understanding of my issue.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

[image: Screen 3]

[image: Screen 4 , Final & Error Screen]

Answer (score 0):

I am working allot with GoogleMeet and never encountered it.
I would suggest you try to reset the browser / try incognito, and if that fails, try another browser.

If all of that doesn't work you could try to share program instead, as a temporary fix until the end of the presentation.

Comment: I have already mentioned I have tried in other browser and it's working. As you suggested I have also tried now with incognito mode & the issue is still the same. Generally when we share screen it creates two screen , one is our own screen & one is cloned screen for presentation but for my issue after I click to present , it is not creating the clone screen which gets use for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Run Chrome as Administrator and go to your meeting. Click on site settings from the icon before the url and allow all the settings.

Comment: Tried now by running chrome as being administrator & also provided allow permission to all the site settings but the problem is still same & the error is same. ( though the needed things were already allowed. like camera/microphone etc as I mentioned I am able to call/video call etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you've gone through all permission settings and see nothing out of place, I'd suggest reviewing your `chrome://flags` with search terms "cast", "screen", "share", "present", etc., enable/disable any that sound pertinent.

Comment: Better yet, click on "Reset All". Also, if you have any open files on Chrome, save them. Chrome will want to reset.